# why after connecting to my wireless router, the positioning is very exact?

Tags: gps

If I connect to my wireless router, the positioning becomes very accurate. However if I am not connected to wireless even though I am near it, the positioning is NOT accurate. I am using a Android LG P-690 phone.

Why connecting to my wireless gives this much more accurate result? Is the position of my wireless registered in some database from the ISP, and how does Android have access to that data?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the position of your wireless is registered somewhere.  Google uses this to find locations.  Your wireless probably got registered by your own phone, at some point you got a good GPS fix while the phone could see your wireless router, and that information got transmitted to google to register that gps position with that router.